# Having issue with Unity 3D Mirror API: Declaring a struct incorrectly

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-mirror

I have the following piece of code in Unity C#. I'm receiving the following two error

The type 'Notification' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'NetworkServer.SendToAll(T, int, bool)'

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Action'

**messagetest.cs**

```
using Mirror;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

namespace DapperDino.Mirror.Tutorials.NetworkMessages
{
public struct Notification : NetworkMessage
{
public string content;
}

public class MessagesTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private TMP_Text notificationsText = null;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (!NetworkClient.active) { return; }

        NetworkClient.RegisterHandler<Notification>(OnNotification);
    }

    private void OnNotification(NetworkConnection conn, Notification msg)
    {
        notificationsText.text += $"\n{msg.content}";
    }
}
```

}

I don't think I'm supposed to declare notification as a type struct, but even leaving it as a class doesn't yield the code operable in Unity 3D. Any idea how I would go about fixing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your handler signature does not match the action.  Remove the `NetworkConnection` parameter from the handling method.

```
private void OnNotification(Notification msg)
{
    notificationsText.text += $"\n{msg.content}";
}
```